# Content Grabber 2 How to collect all emails inside pargraph with RegEx?

Tags: regex, email, text-extraction, data-extraction, webgrabber

I'm using Content Grabber 2 and I have paragraph contains many emails in many parts. I'm using a this software to match case inside any paragraph, HTML or what ever to collect the emails with clean format.

I'm using this syntax:

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b
```

To find all email match. But the issue its always stop after the first match.

As per my knowledge, I need to  make it global to keep working after the first match and its already work on this link:
https://regex101.com/r/Q0wZLJ/1

But not inside my software (Content Grabber 2).

Is it possible to explain what I need to do to make my syntax global in the way I wrote  above?

Thank you,

Comment: "But not inside my software" - what software?

Comment: Thank you , its: Content Grabber 2

Comment: A quick search yields [*`return all` - Returns all matches or the specified group within all matches*](https://contentgrabber.com/Manual/script_languages.htm) (so, you'd need to specify `0` as the group to return) or `return table` (*Returns all matches in a data table.*)

Comment: Thank you again, could you please advise with the correct syntax?

Comment: I tried this
\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b .* and its gave the paragraph which includes the (ALL) Email, how to filter it only to show the emails please?

Comment: No, the `\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b` pattern  is correct (to some extent), just use it properly within Content Grabber.

Comment: Thank you, your help fix my issue. I'm very new on this and I use your link and its working fine, I need only to add "return all" after my command :) Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with the pattern (just mind it won't detect all possible emails, the most lenient pattern for an email is `\S+@\S+\.\S+`). You just need to add `return all` to your command.

See the *Content Grabber* [documentation](https://contentgrabber.com/Manual/script_languages.htm):

> *`return all`*   Returns all matches or the specified group within all matches.

Comment: Thank you, This fixed my problem and help me to understand my question as well. The problem, I did not ask the proper question, but your answer help to make me understand what I need to ask about thats why I changed my question as well.